# Getting Full sized image from camera, Memory Issue

Tags: android, memory-management, camera, photos

I am using this line of code for getting the full sized image, i am not setting this image on any view, still this line when executed takes a lot of ram, around 110-120m, any solutions ? I even tried running this code in Backgroung thread using Async Task. The picture resolution is 4008*5344.

```
Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
```

**And the below method given in developers site, gives me Null bitmap.**

```
private void setPic() {
// Get the dimensions of the View
int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

// Get the dimensions of the bitmap
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

// Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

// Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: If `Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath)` is valid, then `mCurrentPhotoPath` is a valid string representation of a `Uri`, and it is not a path to a file. Hence, using `decodeFile()` will not work. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the `Uri`. Then use `decodeStream()` instead of `decodeFile()`.

Comment: using Content:// type path, Let me try this.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the image once you've loaded it?

Comment: :) its done, like commonsWare said, i needed to use `decodeStream` instead of `decodefile`. Due to changes in naugat, i was using the uri path as `Content:\\` type. +1 for CommonsWare's comment.

Comment: @clownba0t - btw since you asked, i'll be uploading the image directly to server.